How to copy multiple folders along with files from one blob container to another blob within multiple sub-folders using ADF?
I am using ADF pipeline to copy multiple datasets parquet files present in multiple folders from one source blob container (Client container) to our blob container.
However, I don't want to copy it directly as it is. Instead, I want it like below,

As shown above I want following folders along with the files present in them to be copied to the shown destination folders.
I tried with regular copy activity but it doesn't allow me to add multiple wildcards and also doesn't allow me to specify multiple destination in Sink section.
Could you please let me know how can I achieve the above using the ADF pipeline?
Lookup output array for reference.


As you have source and destination folder paths in a file, you can use a copy activity with dataset parameters in a For-Each activity.
First store the above file in a temporary location.
I took the folder paths same as yours.
SourceBlob_Container,DestinationBlob_Container
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_CHANEL_M_AB_202402_20240415,blobdestination/Demo_Tables/Load_04_15_2024
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_CONTROL_M_AB_202402_20240415,blobdestination/Demo_Tables/Load_04_15_2025
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_COMPATIENT_M_665_202402_20240415,blobdestination/M_665/ Load_04_15_2024
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_DIAG_M_665_202402_20240415,blobdestination/M_665/Load_04_15_2025
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_COMPATIENT_M_667_202402_20240415,blobdestination/M_667/Load_04_15_2024
blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_DIAG_M_667_202402_20240415,blobdestination/M_667/Load_04_15_2025

Create a delimited text dataset to this file and give that to a lookup activity with below configurations.

Lookup activity will give the Source and sink folder paths as a JSON array. Take a For-Each activity and give this array @activity('Lookup1').output.value to the For-Each expression.

Inside For-Each, take the copy activity. For the source of the copy activity, take a parquet dataset and create a dataset parameter container_name.

Use this as @dataset().container_name in the dataset container name and leave the remaining path as empty.

For the sink dataset of the copy activity, create another parquet dataset. Here, create two dataset parameters container_name, folder_path.

Use those in the dataset as same as source dataset and leave the file name as empty.

Give these two datasets as source and sink of the copy activity. Now, in the source, select Wild card file path and give the below expressions.
container_name : @first(split(item().SourceBlob_Container,'/'))
wild card folder name : @join(skip(split(item().SourceBlob_Container,'/'),1),'/')
wild card path : *.parquet


Similarly, give the below expressions for the sink dataset parameters.
container_name : @first(split(item().DestinationBlob_Container,'/'))
folder_path : @join(skip(split(item().DestinationBlob_Container,'/'),1),'/')


Now, debug the pipeline and all the parquet files in each source folder path will be copied to its respective target folder in each iteration.

UPDATE:
To copy the source folder of the files to the target location, give the below expressions in the copy activity sink.
container_name : @first(split(item().DestinationBlob_Container,'/'))
folder_path : @concat(join(skip(split(item().DestinationBlob_Container,'/'),1),'/'),'/',last(split(item().SourceBlob_Container,'/')))


Keep the copy activity source as same as above.
It will copy all file in the folder along with folder to the target location.


thanks its working but its copying only the files present in source folder and not the folder itself. I want the source folder as well to be copied into the destination blob.

Additionally, I noticed it copied files of only 1st source folders and not all.

Please check whether the First row only in the lookup disabled or not. For me It copied all source folders files to its respective target folders. I will modify the answer as per the folder copy in some time.

I checked First row only is disabled.

No its showing all my 4 records which i have added in my sample file.  Screenshot above.

If the source path is blobsource/demo/raad/indicated/inbound/IMSONE_CHANEL_M_AB_202402_20240415, Do you mean you want copy all the files present in folder IMSONE_CHANEL_M_AB_202402_20240415 and folder inbound and folder indicated etcc...? correct me if I am wrong.

Can you give sample your source folder path with some files in it and how your target folder structure should be for that?

I want entire "IMSONE_CHANEL_M_AB_202402_20240415" folder which are present under inbound folder and similar folder like it begging with IMSONE word to be copied  as it is with all files into destination folder paths i have mentioned in sample file.   Sorry, i cannot share sample file for now but it would be same as shown in my query above.

Sorry for asking again, please correct me if I am wrong, so you only want to copy the last folder IMSONE_CHANEL_M_AB_202402_20240415 from the source path to along with the parquet files to be copied to the destination path, right?

Check the update section of my answer and let me know if it is not working.

Thanks Rakesh, the solution is working as expected. However, would like to know if is it also possible to implement similar output without the use of file in which we mention the source and destination path and instead define both in pipeline itself?

Your scenario involves copying of the different source folders to different target paths, so you need an array of source and target paths. If you create an array variable and store those paths like lookup activity output array, you can avoid file and lookup activity. But AFAIK without that array, it might not be possible to achieve your requirement.
